# Linq Expression string with inline values

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, nhydrate

I am trying to build expression strings for use with IOC extended nHydrate. When I call ToString() on my expression I get something like this:

```
employee => employee.Username == value( Some type name here )
```

Is there a way to resolve that value call to the actual value?

```
employee => employee.Username == "Captain Spiffy"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a ToString() would only fetch you the end expression result, If it is a real expression tree, Like a Expression> then you can traverse the expressions tree using the Expression Visitor class. Make sure this is not a Func!

-Fahad

Comment: It's an Expression<Func<T,bool>> is that going to cause me problems?

Comment: No, Expression<> would only wrap your Func into an expression tree, You can always get the Func by calling the Compile().